# Delphi Menu OnClick Confirmation

Tags: delphi, menu

Needing a confirmation for an OnClick in a Delphi menu, eg: Show Listing y or no ?

```
  object MenuShowList1: TMenuItem
    Caption = 'Show Listing'
    OnClick = ShowListButtonClick
  end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the user must confirm that s/he indeed wants to see the listing when the menuitem is clicked? In that case you include that check into your handler, ie

```
uses Dialogs;

procedure Form1.ShowListButtonClick(Sender: TObject)
begin
  if MessageDlg('Show Listing?',mtConfirmation, [mbYes,mbNo], 0) <> mtYes then Exit;
  // show listing
  ...
end;
```

Comment: @Muso Please don't ignore comments, and wait until you have an answer, before providing the details essential to the question.

Comment: @ain That said, it's really not worth answering questions like this. A better tack is to persuade the asker to fix the question first, and then we can answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right... however, "nagging" non native English speakers about how they need to improve their question might be quite scary thing for them and make them to give up on SO. So when I think I have a good idea about what the question is I usually try to answer it. If it proves to be completely wrong, it can be deleted, but it helps the OP to better formulate his question.

Comment: @ain MusoBob speaks and writes excellent English. It's just a really poor question. It should not be answered, and should be closed. If MusoBob gives up on SO that's fine. We don't want questions like this. On the other hand, if MusoBob wants to fix the question then it's welcome.

Comment: "Please don't ignore comments, "We" don't want questions like this" sorry there is no email notifications. I replayed to the question " I can only edit the rcdata" if you don't know any way of doing this that is ok. I appreciate you trying to help. I'm sorry if I made it too difficult.

Comment: @Muso The difficulty is not the issue here. The issue is that your question is of such low quality. Why don't you let us help you to make it a good question so that we can help you?